# ASP.NET Core: DbSet to executing raw stored procedure

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.0 and razor pages. The SQL table does not have a primary key and I will not be able to make changes to the SQL table. I am trying to use a stored procedure to retrieve the data from the table and show the resultant data in UI.

Since there is no primary key available, I am getting error as  - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.ValidateNonNullPrimaryKeys. I would like to move the code from DBSet to Raw sql as defined in https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql 
Below is my existing code :

```
//Data - myDbContext

 public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<LOB> lobs { get; set; }

        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        }

// Model  
 public class LOB
    {
        public string Desc { get; set; }
    }

//Index.cshtml.cs

 public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly MyDbContext _dbContext;
        public IndexModel(MyDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }
        public List<LOB> lOBs { get; set; } = new List<LOB>();

                [BindProperty]
        public string[] SelectedLOBs { get; set; }

        public SelectList LOBOptions { get; set; }


        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            lOBs = await _dbContext.Set<LOB>().FromSql(
                              "EXECUTE sp")
                              .AsNoTracking()
                              .ToListAsync();

            LOBOptions = new SelectList(lOBs, "Desc1");
        }
    }

// Index.cshtml

  <select class="form-control" required multiple id="selLOB" asp-for="SelectedLOBs" asp-items="Model.LOBOptions"></select>
```

How to fill the dropdown using context.database property ?
Thanks

Comment: Looks like you need to use Query Types: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/query-types

Comment: Hi. I am using ASP.NET 2.0 and query types is used from 2.1

Comment: Query Types have nothing to do with what version of ASP.NET Core you are using. They belong to Entity Framework Core.

Comment: Hi Mike. In the link- the first statement says - This feature was added in EF Core 2.1 . I am using 2.0

Comment: Either upgrade to 2.1 or you can fall back onto using ADO.NET and converting the data into a collection of LOB instances yourself. You can see how to use ADO.NET at the end of the page that you linked to.

Comment: Hi Mike. Ok. I need help in converting my existing code to using (var context = new SampleContext())
using (var command = context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "SELECT * From Table1";
    context.Database.OpenConnection();
    using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // do something with result
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

For `Asp.Net Core` and `EF Core` are different. `Asp.Net Core 2.0` is corresponding to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.0` and `EF Core 2.1` is correspoinding to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1`, you could refer `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1` in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.0`.

Follow steps below to resolve your issue.

1. Update package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` to V2.2.3 and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` to V2.2.3
2. Change `DbSet` to `DbQuery`

   ```
   public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
   {
       public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
           : base(options)
       {
       }
       public DbQuery<LOB> lobs { get; set; }
       protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
       {
           base.OnModelCreating(builder);
           // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
           // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
           // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Change your razor code.

   ```
   public async Task OnGetAsync()
   {
       lOBs = await _dbContext.Query<LOB>().FromSql(
                         "EXECUTE sp")
                         .AsNoTracking()
                         .ToListAsync();

       LOBOptions = new SelectList(lOBs, "Desc", "Desc", "Desc1");
   }
   ```
4. Change your view

   ```
   <select class="form-control" required multiple id="selLOB" 
       asp-for="SelectedLOBs" asp-items="Model.LOBOptions">
   </select>
   ```